# Problema con react-native run-android en Windows

Tags: react-native

-----------Ambiente--------------------------------

S.O: Windows 10 versión 1709 (compilación de SO 16299.19)

Node: 8.9.1

npm: 5.5.1

react-native-cli:2.0.1

react-native:0.56.0

emulador Nox 6.0.0.0

---

Descripción del problema:

Se intenta ejecutar una aplicación sencilla en el emulador de Android con el comando `react-native run-android`

Se obtiene el mensaje de error que se muestra en la siguiente captura de pantalla.
[image: Error al ejecutar react-native run-android]

Cualquier aporte o sugerencia para solucionar el error será de gran ayuda.

Comment: Mi conexión a la red es muy lenta. Descargué manualmente el gradle-3.5.1-all.zip

Comment: ¿Qué tengo que hacer con el gradle-3.5.1-all.zip? ¿Dónde debo de ponerlo en mi proyecto react native? ¿Debo acaso descomprimirlo?

Comment: Hola Josh, `gradle` es una herramienta que usa internamente React Native para poder compilar la parte nativa de Android de tu proyecto.
Deberías instalarlo de manera global, es decir, no es una dependencia específica del proyecto.

Comment: Gracias Gon. Tu aclaración me ha sido muy útil.

Answer (score 1):

Los errores que se me mostraban eran producto de que no se descargaban correctamente las dependencias de Internet. Se solucionaron los errores una vez configuré correctamente el acceso a internet.